# What is Inch-worm effect in linear queue Data Structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue

What do you mean by inch-worm effect in linear queue Data Structure?

Is it even a valid term in DSA?

I tried Searching all over the internet and some books of renowned author but couln't figure it out.
Even chatGPT failed.

Comment: where did you hear this? There is no standard term like this. However, I am surmising it may resemble the analogy of an inch-worm in a way that when elements are `dequeued` from the `front` and `enqueued` at the `rear`, causing the queue to move forward in the allocated memory space, similar to the way an inchworm moves.

Comment: Can you provide any context at all about what this term means? Was it spoken by a professor? Can you use it in a sentence?

Comment: Yes, it had been in official question paper of a university. reference link: https://vidyamandira.ac.in/pdfs/Prev_Year_Questions/UG/END%20SEM/COMPUTER%20SCIENCE/GENERAL/2013/II%20SEM.pdf

Comment: Really this is painful as far as the University exams are concerned. For genuinely testing students in data structures and algorithms there can be huge number of good and fruitful problems which can be asked but what they're asking some made up terms. sad

Comment:  I agree with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "inch worm effect" in a linear queue data structure is not a standard concept.  It is likely an analogy that your professor made up, discussed in class, and expects you to remember.

If we think about how an array-backed linear queue often works, however, then it does seem to correspond to the way that elements are moved in such a data structure, so this is probably what your prof is referring to:

- As items are added and removed from the queue, the head and tail move toward the end of the allocated space.  The queue gets "compressed" into the end of the allocated space kind of like the way a walking inch worm's body gets compressed toward its forward end.
- When there is no more room at the end of the allocated space, all of the element are are moved back, and possibly the space is re-allocated, all at once so that the elements of the array then occupy the beginning of the allocated space.  This is something like the moment in which an inch worm lifts up its front end and stretches it out, suddenly providing a lot more space for its body to compress into.

If I was asking students to "discuss" this, the key feature that I would expect them to mention is that when all the elements are moved into new positions, the room left at the end of the allocated space must be proportional to the amount of work done.  This ensures that the queue as a whole requires only amortized O(1) time per append or remove operation.

Comment: Appreciated the detailed explaination. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Inchworms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometer_moth) are caterpillars that *"appear to measure the earth as they move along in a looping fashion"*.

[image]

This gives the impression of shrinking and stretching while moving forward.

Queues may behave in a way that has some similarity with this. You may get this "inch worm effect" with a queue that is implemented on top of a (circular) array: as you add items to the queue and then remove some items, then add some again, then remove some, ...etc, the queue stretches and shrinks in the underlying array, while it also moves forward in it.

Comment: Appreicated the explaination easy and quick.